# SQL foreach equivalent for query

Tags: mysql, sql, foreach

Im having difficulties creating a query. I have googled a lot but did not find a fitting solution.
I have a table called 'blog'(parent) and a table called 'entry'(child):

**blog**

- id
- subject
- owner

**entry**

- id
- blog_id
- published (1 = published, 0 = unpublished)
- date_created (timestamp, when created and when published)

A blog has multiple entries. Only published entries are visible to other users.

I want to create a query, which fetches the 10 latest modified blogs. For this, i would probably need a 'foreach' equivalent in SQL to search ALL blogs, and order them by the latest PUBLISHED entry (entry.date_modified) but only IF entry.published = 1

My SQL knowledge is not on a level which allows me to create such a query. 
Additional info: using PHP (codeigniter) with MySQL

I tried this, knowing that it would never work, but it may help you as a reference for what i am trying to accomplish

```
SELECT blog.id
FROM blog
JOIN entry ON entry.blog_id = blog.id
WHERE entry.published = 1
ORDER by entry.date_created desc
LIMIT 0, 10
```

i want my end result to be the 10 blog.id's of which their child entry was published most recenlty. Can someone please help? All help is greatly appreciated.

If this is impossible to achieve in 1 query, perhaps with PHP i can make a foreach statement performing individual queries?

Comment: There's a bug in your example: entry.date_created vs. entry.date_modified...

Comment: You mention the most recent blogs... Do you mean the blog itself as most recent, or the entries that are posted TO a given "Active" blog.  Ex: one blog from 20 days ago gets a fresh post today, vs an actual blog that is "available" 10 days ago... Does the 20-day ago blog win since its entry activity is more recent?

Comment: @DRapp i mean the latter. The 20-day ago blog with the most recent child(entry) is the one which i need shown. The voted answer gave me just that.

Comment: @home you are right, i fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this would work:

```
SELECT blog_id
FROM entry
WHERE published = 1
GROUP BY blog_id
ORDER BY MAX(date_created) DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: Won't `MAX(date_created)'` return a single result?

Comment: @James I believe (confirmation needed) that evaluation of `MAX` in `ORDER BY` is done in the same way as it would have had on the `SELECT`.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably all you need.

```
SELECT blog_id
FROM entry
WHERE published = 1
Group By blog_id
ORDER by date_created desc
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: Hey James, thank you. It seems like it might be just what i need, although PHPmyadmin is giving me syntax errors...:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Group By blog_id LIMIT 0, 10' at line 5

Comment: Yeah, Romain is right.  Just put Group By before the Order By.

Comment: Yes, im sorry Romain, i had not yet read your comment. You are right, great effort guys i think it worked. I will close the the question if i am absolutely sure...sorry, might have been an easy one, but my SQL experience is minimal.

Comment: It's no problem.  I'm not sure why Romain removed his comment on mine and added his answer though.  It was after I edited mine to reflect the correct order.  Odd.

Comment: @James you fix your answer, I remove downvote + comment w/ reason. I added my answer because I don't 100% agree with your answer, although I'm uncertain whether it properly works or not (and don't have time to check :D).

Comment: @Romain Why would you have down voted to begin with when the answer was correct, but just had the group by and order by backwards?  I didn't even notice the down vote either, though.  Just seems odd now that you mentioned it.

Comment: @James syntactically incorrect answer is not correct. So if I see an answer that's syntactically incorrect, I downvote it until its author fixes it.

Comment: @Romain That makes sense, I guess.

Comment: Guys, i just returned from the one-man-party i threw because you solved my problem, only to return and see the ones who made this possible argue about a small detail. The query was good as James posted, and Romain your MAX in the order by clause proved to be just what i needed. So i thank you both equally for helping me!

Comment: I don't really think we were arguing.  I asked him about his Max addition, and didn't even know he marked mine down at first until he said he did.  We were just talking...